# Bypassing value set with InputNumber widget

Tags: jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-3, wijmo

I have an MVC view that is using cached values to display to the user via

```
@Html.TextboxFor(x => x.SomeInteger, new { @class="selector" });
```

and similar constructs.

My problem is that when I do this

```
$(“.selector”).wijinputnumber({
    type: ‘numeric’,
    minValue: 0,
    decimalPlaces: 0,
    showSpinner: true
});
```

The value of the textbox gets set to 0, but (for example) the user could have put in 4 previously and I need it to reflect that. Also, I've verified that my Model does actually have 4 in the SomeInteger property, so it's not that.

Is there a way to tell wijinputnumber to not set an initial value?

Here's a full example of just HTML and Wijmo/jQuery that exhibits this problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="http://cdn.wijmo.com/themes/rocket/jquery-wijmo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="http://cdn.wijmo.com/jquery.wijmo-open.1.1.2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="http://cdn.wijmo.com/jquery.wijmo-complete.1.1.2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.wijmo.com/external/jquery.bgiframe-2.1.3-pre.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.wijmo.com/external/jquery.glob.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.wijmo.com/external/jquery.mousewheel.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.wijmo.com/external/raphael-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.wijmo.com/jquery.wijmo-open.1.1.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.wijmo.com/jquery.wijmo-complete.1.1.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>  
    <input type="text" class="correct" value="5" />

    <input type="text" class="notcorrect" value="10" /> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('.correct').wijtextbox();         

            $(".notcorrect").wijinputnumber({
            type: 'currency',
            decimalPlaces: 2,
            showGroup: true,
            showSpinner: true
            });             
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is a bug in Wijmo currently, but a work around from [this post](http://wijmo.com/groups/community/forum/topic/bypassing-value-set-with-inputnumber/) is as follows:

```
$(“.selector”).each(function () {
var n = $(this).val();
$(this).wijinputnumber(
{
type: ‘numeric’,
minValue: 0,
decimalPlaces: 0,
showSpinner: true,
value: n
});
});
```

Comment: Damn, I should have answered it on here too! Could have gotten the credit. ;) Thanks for posting the answer dude.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the val() function on an element to get its value

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.correct').wijtextbox();         

        $(".notcorrect").wijinputnumber({
            type: 'currency',
            decimalPlaces: 2,
            showGroup: true,
            showSpinner: true,
            value: $(".notcorrect").val()
        });             
    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps,

Matt

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  The problem is my real world scenario actually has multiple textboxes, so $(".notcorrect") is an array of stuff, not a single item.

Comment: @Joseph: Since I can't edit your post! I like your own solution better, but I'm surprised that it has been neglected by the developers.

Comment: they're working on a fix, my answer is just a workaround in the mean time